# Exporting data from SQL Server 2008 r2 Express Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

Is it possible to export data from a SQL Server 2008 r2 Express edition to a Standard edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, make sure you restore the uncompressed backup of your express edition DB

Comment: As long as the Standard edition is at least the same version (2008 R2 or newer) - then yes, this works like a charm